# <list-index ...> --Hibernate mappings

Tags: hibernate, mapping

Two questions about `<list-index...>` :

1. Is it necessary that values of column given in `<list-index ...>` element of `<list>` tag in mappings lists must be unique???

   ```
      <list-index column="index_col"/>
   ```
2. Does hibernate generate values for column in `<list-index>` or we provide them through code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. I don't see why one would use several columns to store a single integer value. The index column stores the index of the element in the list.
2. Hibernate populates this column automatically, from the index of the element in the list.

Comment: `Hibernate populates this column automatically, from the index of the element in the list.`--So it means index col in the DB must be non unique.

Comment: There must be no unique constraint on this column indeed. There could be one on the tuple <FK, index>, but I'm not sure Hibernate wouldn't have problems with such an index if it doesn't order updates appropriately.